# Assigning to data inside class via pointer

Tags: c++

Suppose we have a type like that:

```
struct MyType
{
  OtherType* m_pfirst;
  OtherType* m_psecond;
  OtherType* m_pthird;

  ....
  OtherType* m_pn;
};
```

Would it be a safe way to assign to its members?

```
MyType inst;
....
OtherType** pOther = &inst.m_pfirst;

for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; ++i, ++pOther)
{
   *pOther = getAddr(i);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **safe**?

Comment: No undefined behaviors, memory corruptions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fields are named this way, then you have no choice:

```
inst.m_pFirst = getaddr(0);
inst.m_pSecond = getaddr(1);
...
```

A better struct could be:

```
struct MyType {
    OtherType *m_pFields[10];
}

...
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    inst.m_pFields[i] = getaddr(i);
}
```

As you tagged C++, you can use a ctor:

```
struct MyType {
    OtherType *m_pFirst;
    OtherType *m_pSecond;
    MyType(OtherType *p1,OtherType *p2): m_pFirst(p1), m_pSecond(p2) {};
};
...
MyType inst(getaddr(0),getaddr(1));
```

Comment: Those are not my fields and I cant change it. So i"m thinking of  way how to avoid `inst.m_pFirst = getaddr(0); inst.m_pSecond = getaddr(1); ...`

Comment: I tried and it seems to work. Could you suppose, which problems can appear?

Comment: Yes it will work because its a POD type, but any change about this will cause damages.

Answer (score 1):

```
*pOther = getAddr(i);
```

You assign here to the value of `pOther` not the address. `*` is dereferencing(accessing the pointer content). And `&` is the opposite, getting pointer or referencing.

```
OtherType** pOther = &inst.m_pfirst;
```

Here `&inst.m_pfirst` first `.`(prio. 2) and then `&`(prio. 3), so you get the struct field and then its address. `OtherType** pOther` is pointer on pointer. In short, you change the inner pointer to point to `inst.m_pfirst`. Now you can say for yourself whether that makes sense.

**Ussually I do**:

```
struct mystruct {
int data;
char *arr;
};

struct mystruct *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
s->data = 5;  //same as (*s).data
int n = 3;
*(s->data) = &n; //now its 3
int capacity = s->data;
s->arr = malloc(capacity * sizeof(*(s->arr)))
```

And then you can plug in your address-functions at the appropriate places.

Hopefully that clears it up a little bit.

Comment: `*pOther = getAddr(i);` Since pOther is a pointer to pointer, then when dereferencing it I get a pointer.\n In short, you change the inner pointer to point to inst.m_pfirst \n Exactly. Members of a structure are named in a stupid way and I want to avoid accessing each of them separately.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the proper way. `++pOther` will take you to nowhere. This code will produce undefined behavior.

Comment: in the for loop he/she is expecting the next field of the member pointed by pOther [which I believe, is a user define datatype]

Comment: It's all quite dependent on information OP hasn't provided, but I think this is typically OK; user-defined datatype or not.